# What are your recommendations for reducing the number of resources (JavaScript and CSS) that DotNetNuke loads?

Tags: dotnetnuke

The home page for DotNetNuke 5.2 is around 252.6KB.  It uses 15 JavaScripts and 8 CSS files.  The number of resources DotNetNuke uses seems excessive to me.  I am looking for best practices creating DotNetNuke skins that limit the JavaScript and CSS resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 6.1 onward, the Client Resource Management component is the solution for this.  It automatically combines all your files, cleaning them up, removing comments, and minifying if desired.

http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API.aspx

It takes a little getting used to, but the control is quite nice. You can decide which order they'll go in, you can group the files in bunches if you don't want one big single file - maybe you want certain bunches of scripts together but not all.
One thing to remember is that when you're doing development (as noted by the comment below, which I've since edited this post), **you should always use debug=true in the web.config**, otherwise if you are using Resource Mgmt and change your source files, you'll constantly need to regenerate the combined files by going into Site Settings, Client Resource Management, and increment the version.  It's kind of a protection to keep anything from altering your clients' browser caches without intent (that's the message box that pops up to let you know when you do it). I'm sure if you have a zillion users this might make a difference.

Comment: With regard to developing, turn `debug="true"` on in your web.config and the client resource manager will turn off its combining and minifying.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Unload CSS Skin Object](http://dnnskinextensions.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=31187) to remove links to some of the CSS files loaded by the framework (like Default.css, portal.css & any module-specific CSS files).  You can then move all of those styles into the skin (or portal stylesheet, whichever is your preference), so that there's only one stylesheet that gets loaded.

I don't know of any solutions for combining JavaScript resources or reducing the number of scripts that DNN requires.

Comment: The Unload CSS Skin Object is a great start.  I am also documenting the dependencies for the common JavaScript files used by DNN.  Then only load them when needed.  Seems that some of the JavaScript functionality is primarily used for administration, so I am looking into conditionally loading those scripts.  I'll post the dependency list when I am finished.

Answer (score 1):

Part of that is just the dynamic nature of DNN - there are some good resources that R2i has published about combining javascript and CSS

One concrete suggestion is to combine all your skin and contianer css in one file and if you have full control of the site to combine the css from the modules you use into that same file.

I know with the addition of the Telerik controls there is some abilities to combine resource files

Another thing that helps is to combine graphics into a single file and use CSS (the sprite technique) to cut down number of files loaded and calls to the sever

Answer (score 0):

Like it was stated above, it's the nature of the beast.  Each module will have at least 1 css file included.  You can check out PageBlaster from snapsis.com, I believe it will do what you are looking for.